# Using an array of createObjectURL items to select the src for HTML5 audio tag

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple HTML5/javascript page to play local MP3 files using the HTML5 audio tag, and I'm running into an issue I can't figure out.

I'm using the file input tag to get a list of files, and then using URL.createObjectURL to stuff those files into an array.  Then I want to pull those files out of the array and feed them into the SRC of the audio tag to play them.

This works great for the first file, but anytime I try to fire the event to load another song, the first song loaded plays.

I've inspected the array, and all the elements contain different objects, so that seems okay, however the src never seems to change.

The Javascript:

```
var Files = [];
    var FileNames = [];

    var LoadSong = function()
    {
      var selectedfolder = document.getElementById("folder_select"),
          files = selectedfolder.files,
          audioplayer = document.getElementById("audio_player"),
          audiosource = document.getElementById("mp3_src"),
          a = FileNames.indexOf(this.innerHTML);

      audiosource = Files[a];
      audioplayer.pause();
      audioplayer.load();
      audioplayer.oncanplaythrough = audioplayer.play();
      $("ul li").removeClass("playing");
      this.className = "playing";
    };

    var GetFiles = function()
    {
      if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
      {
      }
      else
      {
        alert("This browser cannot support this upload method");
        return;
      }
      var selectedfolder = document.getElementById("folder_select"),
          files = selectedfolder.files,
          audioplayer = document.getElementById("audio_player"),
          audiosource = document.getElementById("mp3_src");
          songlist = document.getElementById("song_list");

      for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        Files.push(URL.createObjectURL(files[i]));
        FileNames.push(files[i].name);

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.className = 'songlistitem';
        li.innerHTML = files[i].name;
        songlist.appendChild(li);
        li.onclick = LoadSong;
      }

      audiosource.src = Files[6];

      audioplayer.pause();
      audioplayer.load();
      audioplayer.oncanplaythrough = audioplayer.play();
    };

    $(function () {
      $("#folder_select").change(GetFiles);
    });
```

The HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>MusicPlayer</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <audio id="audio_player" controls>
        <source id="mp3_src" type="audio/mp3" />
      </audio>
      <input type="file" id="folder_select" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
      <ul id="song_list">
        <li class="top">These songs have been loaded:</li>
      </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

What seems like should be a stupid simple project, but I can't sort out why it's not working.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: `audioplayer.oncanplaythrough = function(){audioplayer.play();};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out it was an easy fix...  It was me leaving the .src property off the audiosource reference.

Below is the LoadSong method updated to show the fix.  Thanks.

```
    var LoadSong = function() {
      var audioplayer = document.getElementById("audio_player"),
          audiosource = document.getElementById("mp3_src");

      audiosource.src = Files[TrackIndex];
      audioplayer.pause();
      audioplayer.load();
      audioplayer.play();
      $("ul li").removeClass("playing");
      $("li").eq(TrackIndex).addClass("playing");

      chrome.notifications.create('nowplaying', {
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: AlbumArt,
        title: FileNames[TrackIndex],
        message: FileNames[TrackIndex]
      }, function(notificationId){});
    };
```

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by leaving the .src property off the audiosource reference

Comment: In my initial code I had:       audiosource = Files[a];
I needed to have instead:    audiosource.src = Files[a];